# WSO2 BPS source build failure

Tags: wso2

Error when I building from the souce...  the carbon version 4.0.2
svn co https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/dependencies/(4.0.2)

```
Downloading: http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/eclipse/emf/common/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] The POM for uddi:uddi4j:jar:1.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project wsdl-validator: Could not resolve dependencies
 for project org.wso2.wsdl.validator:wsdl-validator:jar:1.2.0-wso2v1: Failed to collect
dependencies for [commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3 (compile), org.apache.ant:ant:jar:
1.7.0 (compile), org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.2.0-v20060603 (compile), org.eclipse.cor
e:resources:jar:3.2.1-R32x_v20060914 (compile), org.eclipse.emf:common:jar:2.3.2 (compil
e), org.eclipse.emf:ecore:jar:2.3.2 (compile), org.eclipse.wst.common:uriresolver:jar:1.
1.201-v200705302225 (compile), org.eclipse.wst:validation:jar:1.1.102-v200709122200 (com
pile), org.eclipse.wst.xml:core:jar:1.1.201-v200709201331 (compile), org.eclipse.wst.com
mand:env:jar:1.0.408.v200903110045 (compile), org.eclipse.wst:ws:jar:1.0.203-v2007090522
19 (compile), org.eclipse.xsd:xsd:jar:2.2.3 (compile), wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.5.3 (compile)
, xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1 (compile), uddi:uddi4j:jar:1.0.1 (compile), com.ibm.icu:ic
u4j:jar:3.8 (compile)]: No versions available for org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:[3.2.0,3.
4.0) within specified range -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the fo
llowing articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionEx
ception
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :wsdl-validator
D:\Work\SOAsource\BPS\bps_platform\dependencies>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are building from carbon version 4.0.2?  Why not build the latest released Business Process Server 3.1.0 which is on Carbon 4.2?  See here for release info - http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the orbit and kernel before building the the platform. If you haven't please do build them and try

Comment: I have already finished for kernel and orbit,When I build platform when the above error.(platform 4.0.2)

Comment: I have already finished for kernel and orbit,When I build platform when the above error.(platform 4.0.2)  http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/uddi/uddi4j/1.0.1/  SVN  not have the pom.xml file.